# How to trigger select box change event manually from component in Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

view.html

```
<select class="form-control form-control-sm" (change)="filterByProgramName()" [(ngModel)]="filterByProgramNameModel" #SelectedShow>
    <option selected="selected" disabled [ngValue]="empty">Select...</option>
    <option *ngFor="let showname of summaryGraphProgramNames" [ngValue]="showname">{{showname.value}}</option>
</select>
```

component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, NgZone, ViewChild, ElementRef, Renderer } from '@angular/core'
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'
import * as $ from 'jquery'
@Component({
    selector: 'app-summary-graph',
    templateUrl: './summary-graph.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./summary-graph.component.scss'],
    providers: [SummaryGraphService]
})

export class SummaryGraphComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild('SelectedShow') SelectedShow:ElementRef
    constructor(public zone: NgZone){}
    manuallyTriggerChangeEvent(value){
        // I am trying to trigger the 'change' event from this function
        // manuallyTriggerChangeEvent is invoked from child component
        // this.filterByProgramNameModel.value = 'new value'
        this.zone.run(() => {        
            this.filterByProgramNameModel.value = value
            // this.SelectedShow.nativeElement.click() ==> working
            this.SelectedShow.nativeElement.change()
            // $(this.SelectedShow.nativeElement).trigger('change')
            //this.filterByProgramName(value)
        })
    }
    filterByProgramName(){
        // some http.get() and update the page value
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error in your code ?

Comment: @PardeepJain: Modified the question: its `.change is not a function`

Comment: Try to call `this.SelectedShow.nativeElement.change()` in `ngAfterViewInit()`, I believe nativeElement is not set before `ngAfterViewInit()`. If it still not working, try to use a `setTimeout()` with a small delay like 100ms (sometimes nativeElement is still not set on `ngAfterViewInit()` startup).

Comment: you want to call ``test()`` right ?

Comment: ``[(ngModel)]`` has ``[ngModel]`` and ``(ngModelChange)`` . so bind a method for ``(ngModelChange)=test($event)`` . ``$event`` has updated model .

Comment: @CruelEngine: as you suggested test is getting called but, model is getting updated but not able to trigger change event manually, updated the question

Comment: @KrishnaKumar its just a matter of calling the ``filterByProgramName()`` inside the ``test()``